# Angular binding does not work in data- attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using some css html template that comes with many html components and with lots of data-attributes for various things. For example for slider it has something like

```
 <div class="slider slider-default">
    <input type="text" data-slider class="slider-span" value="" data-slider-orientation="vertical" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="200" data-slider-value="{{ slider }}" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="hide">
</div>
```

Here I am trying to bind the value

```
data-slider-value="{{ slider }}"
```

But it's not working. Variable 'slider' is set in the $scope as:

```
   $scope.slider = 80;
```

Same value 80 shows up right when I bind it as:

```
 <h4>I have {{ slider }} cats</h4>
```

I have also tried

```
    ng-attr-data-slider-value="{{ slider }}"
```

It didn't work.

### Update

The directive has something like this

```
function slider() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.slider();
        }
    }
};
```

where `element.slider();` calls the code in `bootstrap-slider.js` (from [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/)) for each of the sliders.

Comment: What template are you using that provides these components? We need to know what Javascript is being used to render the slider so we can know what to call. Can you also please try to reproduce this using something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co), [jsBin](http://jsbin.com), [CodePen](http://codepen.io) or the inbuilt snippet support on StackOverflow?

Comment: its a wrapbootstrap template. The template itself is an angular based template. it has directives related to slider as well.

i try to narrow it down in plunkr.

Comment: please review the update if it helps.

Comment: Do you know which `angular-slider.js` is being used. Is it the one from [here](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) or [here](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/)?

Comment: exactly the second one.

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played with this for a while, and came up with a few options for you. See my [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kkdJ6zICeGItlnFERSjN?p=preview) to see them in action.

#### Option 1: No need to update the scope value when the slider changes

This will work with the HTML from your question. The following is what you should change the directive code to.

```
app.directive('slider', function slider() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('sliderValue', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        element.slider('setValue', newVal);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

#### Option 2: Two way binding to the scope property

If you need the scope property to be updated when the slider handle is dragged, you should change the directive to the following instead:

```
app.directive('sliderBind', ['$parse',
  function slider($parse) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var val = $parse(attrs.sliderBind);
        scope.$watch(val, function(newVal, oldVal) {
          element.slider('setValue', newVal);
        });

        // when the slider is changed, update the scope
        // property.
        // Note that this will only update it when you stop dragging.
        // If you need it to happen whilst the user is dragging the
        // handle, change it to "slide" instead of "slideStop"
        // (this is not as efficient so I left it up to you)
        element.on('slideStop', function(event) {
          // if expression is assignable
          if (val.assign) {
            val.assign(scope, event.value);
            scope.$digest();
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

The markup for this changes slightly to:

```
<div class="slider slider-default">
  <input type="text" data-slider-bind="slider2" class="slider-span" value="" data-slider-orientation="vertical" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="200" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="hide" />
</div>
```

Note the use of the `data-slider-bind` attribute to specify the scope property to bind to, and the lack of a `data-slider-value` attribute.

Hopefully one of these two options is what you were after.

Comment: o man thank you so much. o was up many nights to figure this out. really grateful to you. It has cleared many concepts.

Comment: My application is using toggle switch http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/ 

as well. i tried to use the same approach you mentioned above. but it looks like with every component i have change my approach.

i want the same two way binding. i named by directive switchBind. now according to documentation there is no function hat sets the value true or false. i tried hooking to switchChange.bootstrapSwitch event which also doesn't seems to be firing. 

i want to have a uniform approach to address all upcoming UI elements i encounter that you put a watch on something and set something. any suggestion?

Comment: i figured out something like 'setState'

 element.bootstrapSwitch('setState', true );
but still not working

Comment: there is a solution based on ng-bind but cant we do this using the same approach as we did for slider.

Comment: [Try this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IcUWbwGeI6OkrOKwwLMJ?p=preview). In fact, I actually now think using `ngModelCtrl` methods to update the value specified in the `ng-model` attribute is probably the better approach for both widgets. See if you can do it for the slider as well. `ng-bind` is not the way to go, it is one-way binding and sets the `innerHTML` property, rather than the value of an input.

Comment: well this makes sense. but after lots of digging into the code my problem seems to be bit different. 

ill be really great-full if you could take a look at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553086/bootstrap-switch-not-firing-setstate-event-in-angular-directive

Answer (score 1):

I use .attr and it works for me. Try this:

```
attr.data-slider-value="{{slider}}"
```

Comment: Thank God we have Angular 2+ now :)